# Flask is not loading user id from model

Tags: python-2.7, authentication, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to write login app using flask.

My View.py look like

```
@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):

   if id is None or id == 'None': 
       id =-1
   print 'ID: %s, leaving load_user' % (id)
   return Users.query.get(int(id))
```

and another login method is

```
@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html', 
        title = 'Sign In',\
        form = form)


    username = form.username
    password = form.password
    user = Users(nickname = form.username, email = 'sanjeev_yadav248@yahoo.com', role =       
    ROLE_USER)
    if user is None:
        flash('Username or Password is invalid' , 'error')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    remember_me = False
    if 'remember_me' in session:
        remember_me = session['remember_me']
        session.pop('remember_me', None)
    login_user(user)
    flash("Logged in successfully.")
    return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for("index"))
```

My model(model.py) class is

```
class Users(db.Model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
     nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
     email = db.Column(db.String(120), index = True, unique = True)
     role = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default = ROLE_USER)
     posts = db.relationship('Post', backref = 'author', lazy = 'dynamic')

     def is_authenticated(self):
             return True

     def is_active(self):
            return True

     def is_anonymous(self):
           return False

     def get_id(self):
           return unicode(self.id)

     def __repr__(self):
           return '<User %r>' % (self.nickname)
```

My databsase users table is having id,nickname,emailid and role.
This nick name is having sanjeev as a value and associated id with it for example 3. But when I run it, load_user() method id is not populated. i.e it is 'None'. When I hardcode id in load_user method its work fine. for example if I put return Users.query.get(3). Let me know if you guys have any clue in this regard.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [flask-login can't understand how it works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075535/flask-login-cant-understand-how-it-works)

Comment: I had already gone through link provided by you. Can you tell me what special thing I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure your `login` method is indented correctly? Have you gone through the [`flask` tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/)? You have some basic problems with your code; for starters `username = form.username` isn't doing what you think its doing.

Comment: form.username is returning 'sanjeev' to me from browser. I have hard-coded nickname just to make sure I am passing correct value.             Indentation of login method is correct  and I can see message Logged in successfully in browser. I have read flask tutorial carefully that's why asking the questions.