# Trying to implement User Login(Login Manager) with Sqlite3 in Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlite

The problem is that once the user logs in, he doesn't stay logged in. I have a condition on the login page to redirect the user if he is logged in but it doesn't seem to work.

For instance, after logging in, if a user reloads the login page he is asked to log in again. If I add @login_required to any of my routes, I get an unauthorised access error.

What am I missing?

User Class:

```
    class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, username, password, email):
        self.username = username.lower()
        self.password = password
        self.email = email

    def is_authenticated():
        return True

    def is_active():
        return True

    def is_annonymous():
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        conn = connect_db()
        conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute('select uid from user where username = (?)', [self.username])
        return unicode(curs.fetchone())

    def add_db(self):
                curs = g.db.cursor()
        curs.execute('insert into user(username, password, email) values (?, ?, ?)', [self.username, self.password, self.email])
        g.db.commit()
```

Views:

```
    @app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def login():
    print('testttttttttttttttttttttt' + str(g.user.get_id()))
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))       
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        #session['remember_me'] = form.remember_me.data
        g.username = form.username.data
        g.password = form.password.data
        user_db = fetch_user(g.username)
        if user_db is not None:
            if g.password == user_db[2]:
                user = User(user_db[1], user_db[2], user_db[3])
                login_user(user, remember = form.remember_me.data)
                flash('Login successful!')
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
            else:
                flash('Incorrect password.')
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            flash('No such user exists.')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('login.html', title = 'Sign In', form = form)


    @lm.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
    conn = connect_db()
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute('select * from user where uid = (?)', [id])
    return curs.fetchone()

    @app.before_request
    def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()
    g.user = current_user

    @app.teardown_request
    def teardown_request(error):
    if hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db.close()


Let me know if I need to post some other part of my code.
```

Edit- Made the `load_user` method to return an instance of the `User` class but now I get another error.

Code- https://codeshare.io/svdIa

For some reason, the g.user and the current_user objects are being perceived as 
strings rather than instances of User class. The first 2 lines of the login_user method also generate the same error.

Error Trace:

```
File "C:\Python27\asset\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2000, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Python27\asset\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "C:\Python27\asset\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\asset\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\asset\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\asset\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\asset\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\asset\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Python27\asset\flask\lib\site-packages\flask_login.py", line 790, in decorated_view
elif not current_user.is_authenticated:
File "C:\Python27\asset\flask\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'
```

Comment: I referred to this question to implement User Login with Sqlite3 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177548/trying-to-implement-user-loginlogin-manager-with-sqlite3-in-flask

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a cookie (typically) or authorization headers which your app will check to be a valid logged in user.

Otherwise, the user's browser has to way to tell your application that it's logged in and there's nothing in your app which is identifying that user as someone who just logged in validly.

On your line:

```
login_user(user, remember = form.remember_me.data)
```

Should be:

```
login_user(user, remember=True)
```

That sets the cookie. Also, based on how the login works, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081788/1431750) and this part [from the docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-using-authorization-header).

`load_user` should be returning an instance of `User` and not a cursor as you've done `return curs.fetchone()`. Instead do:

```
u = curs.fetchone()
return User(u['username'], u['password'], u['email'])
```

This is also wrong because you shouldn't need this much info to create the User instance. And does your `id` equal a primary key or is it actually the username?

I suggest you read more of the docs and the answer I linked above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But, isn't that part handled by LoginManager? If not, what is the use of the statement `g.user = current_user`?

Comment: My id is the uid field which is the primary key. I made the suggested changes but got another error. Updated my question. The load_user method calls the get_id method inside the User class to get its argument, right?

Comment: `get_id` has `return unicode(curs.fetchone())`. You need to use that to create a `User` instance in `load_user` instead of just returning it. There are too many things going on and you need to break it down to smaller parts yourself before someone here can help.

Comment: Thanks for being so patient with me. I have removed the irrelevant routes and methods. Try looking at it now- https://codeshare.io/svdIa