# Validate login using javascript from a login page by clicking on "Login button"

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python

Suppose  I have  a  javascript for  a "Log in" button  in a  login.html page.  The   javascript   can look like this

```
var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
if ( username == "Formget" && password == "formget#123"){
alert ("Login successfully");
window.location = "success.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
return false;
}
else{
attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
alert("You have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
// Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
if( attempt == 0){
document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
return false;
}
}
}
```

In the   code  where  I do `if ( username == "Formget" && password == "formget#123")` I  have   2 screnarios

1)  I   need   to   get a  list  of users  from  2  separate external  MYSQL  databases and concatenate to form  a  list  of users who are elgible   to login.( In can  write  a  python script to generate that list, no issues)

2) The  users  who are eligible   to login needs   to   be validated against a LDAP  link  to authenticate their password. Only then they can enter the  home page.

I am using a  flask application(using apache  and mod_wsgi to run it). Though  flask has   its own way of handling this, I am bit confused of  a convenient way to handle this. Please  help, I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems here.

1. If you are using Flask you should be handling most logic in the back-end, such as in your views.
2. User authentication (and security in general) should be handled server-side, not client-side. JavaScript (in this case anyways) is used entirely for client-side logic.

Now that that's out of the way, the usual way that people handle user authentication in Flask is by using [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The documentation that I linked goes over setting up your application, installing the proper dependencies, and how to login/logout among other things.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081788/6595282) also has some good information about the database and user model side of things, as well as linking to a good example of a complete working user authentication system.