# AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to run my Flask Application and I keep getting the following Error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'get'
```

I'm assuming it's coming from my Models.py code:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    #posts = db.relationship('Post', lazy='dynamic')


    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        return self.email

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return self.authenticated

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False


    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(userid):

        return User.get(User.id==userid)
```

After playing around, it looks like I may need the following code block somewhere or a variation of?:

```
def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user
```

Or some type of derivative of that. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the full traceback:

```
 form = PostForm()
[2018-07-06 11:08:23,652] ERROR in app: Exception on /index [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"/Users.../sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 682, in __getattr__
return getattr(self.comparator, key)
AttributeError: 'Comparator' object has no attribute 'request'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/...python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in 
wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/...b/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in 
full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Users/...python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in 
handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users//python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in 
reraise
raise value
File "/Users/...python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in 
full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Users/WilliamStevens//site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in 
dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
 File "/Users//Documents/deplorable_snowflake/.../views.py", line 52, in 
index
return render_template('frontpage.html', form=form, posts=posts)
File "/Users/.../python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 133, 
   in render_template
  ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
    File "/Users/W/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 792, in 
   update_template_context
   context.update(func())
    File "/Users/.../flask_login/utils.py", line 368, in 
   _user_context_processor
   return dict(current_user=_get_user())
  File "/Users/.../python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 
  335, 
  in _get_user
  current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "/Users/.../python3.6/site- 
  packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", 
  line 359, in _load_user
  return self.reload_user()
  File "/Users/.../lib/python3.6/site- 
  packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 321, in reload_user
   user = self.user_callback(user_id)
   File 
  "/Users/.../models.py", line 53, in load_user
  return User.get(User.id==userid)
  File 
 "/Users/WilliamStevens/.../models.py", line 47, in get
 return self.request.user
    File "/Users/...site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 688, 
  in 
 __getattr__
  key)
 AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' 
 object has an attribute 'request'
```

Comment: It looks like you should handle the user backend by yourself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075535/flask-login-cant-understand-how-it-works.... The load_user seems not part of User class, see also https://gist.github.com/bkdinoop/6698956

Comment: is the `load_user` function part of your model as the indentation in your code suggests?

Comment: Here is the full traceback:

Comment: @shmee i'm not sure? how can i go about finding that out?

Comment: Huh? I was under the impression you wrote that code. Surely you will know if you added the `load_user` to your User class. Also, the traceback you posted is from _after_ you implemented Joel's answer below and does no longer show the AttributeError you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @shmee I added the load_user function under the User class - it's in my models.py code above near the very bottom. Perhaps I need to add it another way? [sorry if i'm not following you]

Comment: Based on what I see in your code snippet for Models.py, it does belong to the User class, it seems to be a method of it. That's wrong. Also, since you seem to be using flask-sqlalchemy, the way to get User objects by their primary key is via `User.query.get(userid)`

Answer (score 9):

I just had this problem.  shmee's proposed solution is what worked for me:

1. The `load_user()` function should not be a part of the `User` class, but instead its own standalone function.
2. The `load_user()` function should call `User.query.get(user_id)`, not `User.get(user_id)`.

   - I think this confusion comes from the fact that Flask-Login's documentation [has it the latter way](http://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works) as of today: `return User.get(user_id)`.

Example code:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Im working with SQLAlchemy. My `User` class looks like this

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
```

I had this, which gave me the error:

```
  @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.get(id)
```

And I change it to this:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
```

The point of `load_user` function is to get `User` object, to load it. I really dont know why `User.get(user_id)` doesnt work, but I retrieve a row from the table the I usually do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Nathan Wailes and @shmee. These solutions fixed my issue too.

@will - it's better to inherit UserMixin class along with db.Model class for User model instead of explicitly writing the code for below methods:

- is_active
- is_authenticated
- is_anonymous
- get_id

```
class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

Then in app.py (main application class), you can add below code before calling the login, logout, etc.., end points:

```
# It should be placed outside of the class
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    return User.query.get(userid)
```

You can refer Flask-Login documentation here: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/